# Ignoring files in git cvsimport

Tags: git, cvs

How can we ignore certain files / directories when we are migrating the repository from cvs to git by using git cvsimport?

Kindly help me.

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either skip files with:

`git cvsimport -S <regex_of_files_to_skip>`

Or, you can use `cvsps` options with `git cvsimport -p <cvsps_options>`

The `cvsps` options you might consider are for example `-l`, `-f`, or `-b`, although these specific what to include, not what to exclude.